# Mule HTTP POST `form-data` conversion to Map

Tags: http, http-post, mule

My mule application is receiving a HTTP POST request with the `Content-Type` as `multipart/form-data`. I tried to use a custom transformer but do not know how to access the paramters as the object is of class `ContentLengthInputStream`.

1. How do I access the form parameters?
2. I want to convert the parameters into a map. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use #[message.inboundAttachments[payload] in a flow, for example, to send a http outbound endpoint:

```
<message-properties-transformer doc:name="Message">
    <add-message-property key="Content-type" value="multipart/form-data/>
</message-properties-transformer>
<http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" method="POST" doc:name="HTTP" address="http://localhost:9090" mimeType="multipart/form-data"/>
```

To receive can be used:

```
<http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8090" connector-ref="HTTP_HTTPS" doc:name="HTTP" contentType="multipart/form-data"/>
<logger message="#[message.inboundAttachments[payload]]" level="ERROR" doc:name="Logger"/>
```

You can use a transformer(AbstractMessageTransformer) and get the payload with:

```
DataHandler inboundAttachment = message.getInboundAttachment("AttachmentName");
```

Comment: I am unable to access the form parameters like this. They are not coming as `InboundAttachment`s. I am getting `null` values.

Comment: My client was adding a `application/xml` header. That is why I was getting error. It's fixed now. Thanks.